# LIKE in .where with audited gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, acts-as-audited

I would like find audited changes of state but i dont know who find audited changes from any states

I try this and its work but i would like find last audited change from any states to offboarded:

```
product.audits.where("audited_changes LIKE '%state:%published%offboarded%'").last
```

I would like something like this: `LIKE '%state:%ANY WORD%offboarded%'`

audited change format:

```
audited_changes: {"state"=>["published", "offboarded"]}
```

I want find this result too for example:

```
audited_changes: {"state"=>["hidden", "offboarded"]}
```

I use Rails with postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `@>` operator ("contains" operator) in your `where` clause:

```
product.audits.where("audited_changes @> '{\"state\": [\"published\", \"offboarded\"]}'")
```

Docs for different data types:

- For arrays: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html
- For JSON: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html